# Css border like in google's signup form

Tags: css

What kind of border style is this? It is like elevated against in the background. I searched in the net and I can't find it, so here I am.

Check google's border style in their signup form:
[image: Check google's border style in their signup form]

Comment: Well inspect the element and see what styles are applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp).
Here's a [generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow).